# std::vector<bool>::reference with std::exchange

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, stl, clang, c++14

Is there a technical reason why std::exchange does not work on std::vector::reference or is it a bug in the implementation of GCC and Clang? [With MSVC it compiles fine](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v-24MT).

I have a setup like this (minimal example)

```
struct Manager
{
  std::vector<bool> lifeTimes;

  //Should return the state before trying to kill it
  bool kill(std::size_t index)
  {
    return std::exchange(lifeTimes[index], false);
  }
};
```

std::exchange would make this a really nice one liner but GCC complains about:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::_Bit_reference&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::vector::reference’ {aka ‘std::_Bit_reference’}

So it seams it complains about the `false` [since only the second parameter is an rvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug, MSVC compiles your code because it has an extension which enables binding temporary object (Rvalue) to non-const Lvalue reference.

Below code compiles with MSVC:

```
void foo(int& i) {}
foo(20); // you are passing Rvalue and it is bound to Lvalue reference
```

Above code doesn't compile under G++ or CLang, when you add `const` to make reference to 
const Lvalue, it works:

```
void foo(const int&){}
foo(20); // you can bind Rvalue to const Lvalue reference
```

A few words about vector. `operator[]` for `vector<T>` where `T` is every type except bool returns `T&`:

```
T& vector<T>::operator[](index) // where T is not bool
```

For `bool` vector class template has specialization. Values of `bool` are stored to hold one bit space, because you cannot use address-of operator for one bit, `vector<bool>::operator[](index)` cannot return reference. `vector<bool>` has inner *proxy* class which manipulates bits (call this class as *reference*).

```
vector<bool>::reference vector<bool>::operator[](index)
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

as you see object of *proxy* is passed by value.
So when you call

```
return std::exchange(lifeTimes[index], false);
```

you are passing temporary objecy (Rvalue) to `exchange` which takes first argument by reference to non-const Lvalue. This is the cause that G++ discards this code. If you want to compile it you can explicitly create Lvalue object of *proxy* class and pass it:

```
  bool kill(std::size_t index)
  {
      std::vector<bool>::reference proxyForBit = lifeTimes[index];
    return std::exchange(proxyForBit, false);
  }
```

Comment: You should probably also mention that nowadays people should be compiling with -permissive- to enable standards compliance: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xpUHzG